# When setting up an SSH tunnel user, authorized_keys directive "command=" blocks "permitopen" (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: ssh, unix, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up a user account in Ubuntu 19.10 that can only set up a tunnel for port forwarding on a specific port (9229). I've created the user with a minimal home folder (just a `.ssh` folder and `.ssh/authorized_keys` file). I've gotten the private key login working (and have since disabled password login). Now here is my `authorized_keys` file:

```
permitopen="localhost:9229",no-pty,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command="/bin/echo 'Remote shell access has been disabled'" ssh-rsa KEY USER@HOST
```

Now when I try to set up the tunnel with `ssh -i KEY -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 USER@HOST sleep 10`, I just get `Remote shell access has been disabled`. If I remove the `command=...` part, there's no problem, but then the user can get up to all kinds of stuff.

What am I doing wrong?

I am basing my method on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021/allow-user-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-but-nothing-else

I have tried moving the `permitopen` directive after and before the `command` directive. I also have tried `permitopen=127.0.0.1:9229` and `permitopen=:9229`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR run this command instead, with optionally the `-f` option also added:

```
ssh -N -i KEY -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 9229:localhost:9229 USER@HOST
```

note also that it's using `localhost` and not `127.0.0.1` (see later).

---

There's one thing you didn't follow in the linked answer: this answer is using the option `-N` to not even open an SSH channel to run commands, while you're using the command `sleep 10`. Depending on the usage context, the `-N` option is best complemented with the `-f` option to fork ssh running after (if needed) asking the passphrase and keep it running in the background.

Normally, using `sleep 10` allows to not pile up multiple SSH connections, especially if run automatically, but since you're also using the option `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`, this achieves the same goal: any further command can only fail and not stay connected, since only the first ssh command will be able to listen on local port 9229 and succeed.

I said normally, because you are providing a `command` option which overrides any command tried: an echo command displaying `Remote shell access has been disabled`.

Since the SO answer was done, time has passed, and newer options have appeared, like the [`restrict`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/383f10fb84a0fee3c01f9d97594f3e22aa3cd5e0) option:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,permitopen="localhost:9229",command="/bin/echo 'Remote shell access has been disabled'" ssh-rsa ...
```

which allows *nothing* (but strangely still grants a shell access without using the `command` option), including future unknown features added in future versions of openssh, except what comes after `restrict`: `port-forwarding` itself limited with `permitopen="localhost:9229"`.

If you still want to display a message when a command is attempted, just change it with something more useful for the end user:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,permitopen="localhost:9229",command="/usr/bin/printf 'Remote shell access has been disabled\nPlease run ssh with the option -N (and optionally -f)\n'" ssh-rsa ...
```

Finally this will still not work with your example. The documentation about [`permitopen`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/authorized_keys.5#permitopen=_host:port_) states:

> Multiple permitlisten options may be applied separated by commas.
>   [...]
>   No pattern matching is performed on the specified hostnames, they must
>   be literal domains or addresses.

That means that if you allow `localhost` you must provide `localhost` and not `127.0.0.1` in the request from the client. Else you might get this error on client side, *only* after attempting to use the tunnel:

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

and the corresponding log on server side:

```
sshd[7851]: Received request to connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 9229, but the request was denied.
```

If you want to allow both, permit both. Here's my suggested final version:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,permitopen="localhost:9229",permitopen="127.0.0.1:9229",command="/usr/bin/printf 'Remote shell access has been disabled\nPlease run ssh with the option -N (and optionally -f)'" ssh-rsa ...
```

Comment: What an amazing answer! Thanks so much, everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: `Please run ssh with the option -N...` nice touch!!